# How to define an array of pointers to array of pointers in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Lets say I have the following pointer arrays:

```
const char* m1[5] = { "bla", "asdada", "sadasde", "wrskm", "adjsad" };
const char* m2[5] = { "xxx", "yyy", "zzz", "uuu", "vvv" };
const char* m3[5] = { "lkkl", "kkk", "lkkl", "skl", "jkljkl" };
const char *m4[5] = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };
```

I just want to represent the data above in a single array where each element represents one of the array above. like array of array of pointers to cons char structure(corrected me please if this saying wrong) I try to do the following but it doesn't work

```
char *(const char* exm[5])[4] = { &m1, &m2, &m3, &m4};
```

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element. For an array of pointers, that becomes a pointer to a pointer, i.e. `const char **` for your arrays `m1` to `m4`.

So you need an array of pointer to pointers:

```
const char **exm[] = { m1, m2, m3, m4 };
```